# Companion sample Xcode project for "Apple Help Programming Guide"?

Tags: cocoa

Does anyone know of a sample Xcode project that demonstrates how to provide user help and which closely follows the guidelines of the ["Apple Help Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/)?

The [guide's revision history](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_dochistory/user_help_revhistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH215-TPXREF101) shows that one of the more recent new guidelines is to [organize help books in a bundle](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-TPXREF104). I'm experiencing some trouble following this guideline. Unfortunately AFAIK the guide does not make any mention of a downloadable sample Xcode project; and I cannot find any application installed on my 10.5 system with a help book organized into a bundle.

Does anyone know of a sample project or at least an open-source project which follows this "help book in a bundle" guideline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link provides a step-by-step guide:
http://www.codefreeze.net/documentation/step-implement-an-htmlbased-apple-help-bundle-for-snow-leopard.html

It's written for XCode3 but it worked for me using XCode4 (project's info.plist no longer displayed). The guide is bit wordy but 3 pages cover the whole process.

Apple Help Bundles can be found in
**/Library/Documentation/Help**
as with all bundles you have to Ctrl-Click -> Show Package Contents to see directory structure.

Many of Apple's own applications use the old Apple Help but Mail uses the new (10.6) bundle help. Look in this directory:
**/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Resources/Mail.help**

Hope this helps.